# What is the type for currency?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, openapi

I can't find [a sample](http://editor.swagger.io/) of currency data type in the object definition, nor [a document](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/tutorials/writing-swagger-definitions) on the subject.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [no built-in "currency" type](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/889). You would typically use `type: number` with an optional `format` modifier to indicate the meaning of the numeric type:

```
type: number
format: currency
```

`format` can have arbitrary values, so you can use `format: currency` or `format: decimal` or whatever your tool supports. Tools that recognize the given `format` will map the value to the corresponding type.

Comment: Well. 'type: string' would avoid problem with generated code out of this spec. This is why a lot of APIs expect strings for prices and money..

Comment: Acceptable values for format field are not well defined. You can use any string.A registry of common formats is in progress and "decimal" is the best-fit field proposed for addition to that registry today. https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/845#issuecomment-378139730

Comment: according to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/ nor decimal nor currency is accepted.

Answer (score -5):

The type in the [OpenAPI 2.0](https://swagger.io/specification/#dataTypes) standard closest to typical decimal dollar values seems to be type **number**, format **float**, which is a 32-bit floating point format (see other online discussions such as [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/316))

Comment: Using floats for currency is very dangerous. If you do any maths on it, you'll end up with prices like $43.00000000000000000001  when you're expecting $43.0

Comment: The float format is suitable is ONLY on the API level (note this is a question about "Swagger") where again no better fractional format appears to be standardized (see the link to OpenAPI types again). Of course you have to be careful and check your math ops in the application, where the language hopefully supports something like decimal or outright currency.

Comment: I don't think float is suitable at the API level if you know you're handling decimal values. Specifying float is likely to result in consumers of the API accidentally using floating point values, which are known to not map accurately to decimal values. It would be better to use a different format, such as one of the ones suggested by Helen.

Comment: Yes, except - again - the "decimal" or currency format is not supported by the standard and I certainly worked with Swagger tool(s) that checked and didn't allow such definition. That was a much more real constraint than [theoretical] risks with deserialisation. And how else would you "know you are handling decimal values" from the API definition. from property name? Anyway.